# ordenar de mayor a menor y de manera aleatoria!

Tags: java

tengo la siguiente consulta. Como implementarian el siguiente requerimiento: se deben seleccionar los tres puntajes mas altos, y si hay mas de 3 entre los mas altos, se debe seleccionar de manera aleatoria. por ejemplo, dos participantes tienen 100 puntos, y otros dos tienen 90. se debe hacer aleatorio entre los dos que tienen 90. muchas gracias!

Comment: ya intenté con sort y random, pero no sabria como hacer para que se aplique solo a los dos puntajes mas bajos.

Comment: Para poder apoyarte mejor, te recomiendo que anexes a tu pregunta el código que has intentado hacer o cualquier referencia que tengas, si tienes dudas sobre la pregunta te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: aun estamos en el seudocodigo, pero la duda nos surgió al pensar como lo ibamos a implementar